# Result of GetFromJsonAsync not computed

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2019

I have been using web deploy for a long time, but somehow, now it will not deploy. What's going on with my certificate? and how can i fix it.

```
   Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("xxxx.xxxx.com") using the specified process ("Web Management Service"), but could not verify the server’s certificate. If you trust the server, connect again and allow untrusted certificates.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED.)
    
    Connected to the remote computer ("xxxx.xxxx.com") using the specified process ("Web Management Service"), but could not verify the server’s certificate. If you trust the server, connect again and allow untrusted certificates.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED.
    The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
    The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already provided in the error message, you can refer to this link: [ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED).

**Diagnosis**: The certificate presented by the Web Deploy endpoint is untrusted or invalid. This typically happens if the remote server has a self-signed certificate for the Remote Agent Service or the Web Management Service.

**Resolution**: Either install a trusted certificate on the endpoint, or try bypassing certificate validation.

- From the msdeploy.exe command line, you can do this by passing the
  -allowUntrusted flag.
- From the Visual Studio 2010 publish UI, you can check "Allow
  untrusted".
- From a Visual Studio 2010 deployment package (e.g. MyApp.deploy.cmd),
  you can pass the -allowUntrusted flag.

Comment: But bypassing is just a way of ignoring the issue. My issue is that it works for all others to the deploy with web deploy. So why is it, my machine thinks this certificate should be wrong.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.